# Android sizes to supply an application logo

Tags: android, xml, image

I am including a logo for my application in my app. The logo will span the whole screen when the device is in portrait mode.

**What width images should I include in my app and where should I include them?**

I was thinking 320px, 480px, 600px and 720px width.

**How should I load each one based on the device specific screen properties** - I'm thinking via XML or programatically?

Speed is my primary concern.

---

**EDIT**
I know about different screen densities (hdpi, mdpi etc) but what *dimensions* in pixels should I supply my logo?

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at the developer guide, about supporting multiple devices: [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

In particular:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

I suggest you these resolutions:

```
xhdpi: 720x1280
large-hdpi: 640x960
hdpi: 480x640
mdpi: 320x480
ldpi: 240x320
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to write special code for this as android will automatically choose the appropriate image size. Just put images of different sizes in different folders named as

`drawable-ldpi`- for small resolution,
`drawable-mdpi` -for medium resolution,
`drawable-hdpi` - for high resolution
`drawable-xhdpi` - for xtra high resolution.

You can use [this](http://coh.io/adpi/) link to decide what image size will be suitable for which folder.